# Truncate Mysql Table Cron Job?

Tags: mysql, cron

I am having some trouble on how to Truncate a Mysql Table with a cron job. No matter what I try I can't seem to get the database to clear out the table.. Thanks for the help.

```
mysql -uderp_example -pexample -hlocalhost -Dexample -e"TRUNCATE TABLE juicebox"
```

I am using this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUmow.png

&& /var/lib/mysql/fruitloops_juicebox adding the path still doesn't solve the issue... I don't understand whats wrong.

Comment: Does the command you provided work? If not - how is it relevant to cron?

Comment: Sorry, Its a cron job I must have mistaken it. No the code does not work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the command used, provided you use valid credentials and object names. Error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely reason your command is failing is that you didn't provide an absolute path for mysql. Do it this way

```
/path/to/mysql -uderp_example -pexample -hlocalhost -Dexample -e"TRUNCATE TABLE juice box"
^^^^^^^^
```

It should work just fine.

It's because cron executes under an account which either does not have PATH defined or does not include a path to mysql.

---

Now there is another option - using a [MySQL event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)

```sql
CREATE EVENT update_date_column 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS NOW()
  DO TRUNCATE TABLE juicebox;
```

If you'll decide to go with an event approach:

- use [`SHOW EVENTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-events.html) to list created events with their attributes (e.g. `status`)
- use [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) to check if the event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
- use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
- More on configuring event scheduler read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: @HamAndCheese You're quite welcome. I'm glad it all worked out for you. Good luck :)